# Auto instrumentation like Spring Cloud Sleuth in Node.js

Tags: node.js, zipkin

While Zipkin sdk is available for Node.js, I'm looking for auto-instrumentation like Spring Cloud Sleuth in Node.js app. Is there a module or framework for it in Node.js?

What I mean by auto-instrumentation above is that in Java I don't have to write code to instrument servlets/filters/rest clients with Zipkin. Sleuth automatically does that. While Zipkin instrumentation seems manual in Node.js.

Comment: Have you heard of [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/)? You can use it to [trace with Zipkin](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/sandboxes/zipkin_tracing). But you'll still need to propagate tracing headers.

Answer (score -1):

you can use node-sleuth package for this :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sleuth?activeTab=explore

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This package doesn't work  .